# Limit the number of pagination in ionic slides

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, pagination, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I make the pager to display a maximum of 10 bullets in Ionic?
Currently there are over 50 slides and the pager is showing over 50 dots(bullets) which is highly undesirable. 
Is there any mechanism through which I can set the maximum amount of pagination bullets?
I have set pager=true and would like to display only 10 pagination's.
It would help if there are any SAAS variable's that can be overridden to display only 10 pagination's.
The pagination is required and cannot be ignored by setting pager=false due to customer requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize bullets by options->renderBullet, for example:
for Ionic 4:

in .html file:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" [options]="options">
```

in .ts file:

```
options = {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      if (index < 10) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
      }
      return '';
    },
  },
}
```

Or you can use Dynamic Bullets , that shows max 5 dots with some transition animation:

```
options = {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        dynamicBullets: true,
      },
    }
```

for Ionic3 try like this:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.slides.renderBullet= function (index, className) {
      if (index < 10) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
      }
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

or for dynamic Bullets:

```
this.slides.dynamicBullets = "true";
```

and in html:

```
<ion-slides #slides pager="true">
```

Comment: I tried. However it looks like [options] isn't available in ionic v3. The official documents mentions nothing about it and recommends to use 'Inputs'. However the link to 'input' is broken.

Comment: I edited answer for ionic3, I didn't test it , but it should be worked.